# JavaScript global not keeping scope? creating an autocomplete webservice json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services

Hi I am trying to autocomplete a list of cities, but the json object returned is not formatted for use in autocomplete that requires a field called "label":"cityname" to display the autocomplete, so i am trying to reformat the json object using an ajax call and writting it to a global variable, the issue is that once the ajax call returns, my jsData is [] an empty array... What am I doing wrong? and why doesn't the global variable keep a value?

http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/27/jQuery-Mobile-Autocomplete-now-available

```
<script>
        $("#nec").bind("pageshow", function(e) {
            var jsData = [];

            $.ajax({
                   url: "http://localhost:8084/REST/resources/cities",
                   data:{},
                   type: 'GET',
                   crossDomain: true,
                   dataType: 'jsonp',
                   jsonp: 'jsonp',
                   jsonpCallback: 'jsoncallback',
                   error: function(error){
                       console.log(error);
                   },
                   success: function(result) {
                       for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                             jsData.push({label:result[i].name, value:result[i]}); 
                        }
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(jsData));   
                       },
                });

            $("#textinput").autocomplete({
                target: $('#suggestions'),
                source: jsData,
                minLength: 1
            });

});
    </script>
```

I am a little fresh on the JS front, so there are a few things that I still have not got a hang of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `jsData` isn't global, but scoped inside the anonymous function.

```
    var jsData = [];   // make that here.

    $("#nec").bind("pageshow", function(e) {

        $.ajax({
               url: "http://localhost:8084/REST/resources/cities",
               data:{},
               type: 'GET',
               crossDomain: true,
               dataType: 'jsonp',
               jsonp: 'jsonp',
               jsonpCallback: 'jsoncallback',
               error: function(error){
                   console.log(error);
               },
               success: function(result) {
                   for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                         jsData.push({label:result[i].name, value:result[i]}); 
                    }
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsData));   
                   },
            });

        $("#textinput").autocomplete({
            target: $('#suggestions'),
            source: jsData,
            minLength: 1
        });
```

Although, i wouldn't advise a global variable. But, if it works for you, it's your wish.

Comment: I tried that too, that copy paste is actually my 10th attempt to make it work. that results in jsDAta being [] the same.

Comment: hum I actually tried that again and this time it worked, so it seems to have an inconsistent behavior... hum...

Answer (score 2):

You have to put

```
 $("#textinput").autocomplete({
     target: $('#suggestions'),
     source: jsData,
     minLength: 1
 });
```

within your `success()` function.

Because, `jsData` becomes update within `success()`. Execution of `pageshow` event's anonymous function is faster than execution of `success()`. So, within that function `jsData` remain empty.

You can retrieve data through autocomplete itself. [**See here**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

Comment: ill give that a try, I actually tried to do the reverse, add the ajax call to source: of the autocomplete as a callback, and that did not work. Is there a simpler solution to get a json object and format it? it's a huge amount of code to do such a simple task.

Comment: @thecodeparadox Unfortunately it's not the same auto-complete. This auto-complete is for jquery mobile, as a last resort I may use jquery ui but I did not want to add jQ UI to the project just for auto-complete.